# Multiple REST Feeds to MYSQL Database - Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, rest

I've got a number of REST feeds I'd like to store in a MYSQL database, can anyone suggest a solution for this? Something PHP related appreciated....

Comment: You are asking for help...  Would you kindly take the time to be specific enough to get a good answer?

Comment: Not sure how more specific I can be, REST Feed -> Into -> Mysql DB

Extract various details from the feed and write them to a database.

Comment: You can readthem and then create a function using PHP that you pass all the fields that  you want to save on the database. you must execute this file when you want all this feeds to go on the DB or either use a cronjob. hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not PHP related, but PERL has both a REST interface and a DBI interface (for interfacing with MYSQL).

http://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::REST

There are many other REST interfaces for Google, Twitter, etc.  Just search CPAN modules at search.cpan.org

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no such thing as a REST feed.  There are RSS feeds and Atom feeds, so I will assume you are talking about one of those.

Both are based on XML so I suggest you find an XML parser for PHP and do an HTTP request to get the feed contents, parse the XML into a DOM and then copy the DOM data into MYSQL!

I'm not sure how to be more precise.

Are you looking for someone to write the code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm assuming you are talking about "RSS" feeds. Here's a great opensource library that makes it easy -- http://simplepie.org/ . Point it at an RSS or Atom feed, it will give you back PHP arrays and objects. From there you can interpret them and save them any way you want.

Depending on what you actually want to do with the database, you could use RSS as an XML clob format. Not fast, but easy. Again, it totally depends on what you want to do with the database.